# Just installed the latest siunitx and it says that expl3 is too old

Tags: errors, siunitx

Just installed the latest siunitx and it says that expl3 is too old. I looked on the miktex package update manager and I appear to have the latest version of everything.

The package that now contains the expl3.sty file is l3kernel and it says that it was packaged on 2011-07-11 and installed on 2011-07-20.

Not sure what to do. I need to compile and submit my thesis in a couple of days.

Comment: Update the entire installation, `l3kernel` has been updated several times since July.

Comment: As @deleif says, there has been a re-arrangement and the code is now in `l3kernel` and `l3packages`. To get MiKTeX to install these you need to sync. your package repository.

Comment: i have sync.ed the repository, but it still says the latest version is 11th July. I have found a temporary solution, though I can't be sure if there are some subtle problems caused by it. I managed to install the latest (sept 5th) version of l3kernel from the ctan website. but it is experimental apparently. Sorry Joseph, i left a kind of awkwardly phrased note on your bitbucket site. I was panicking a bit :S

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found for this involved finding and downloading the relevant package on ctan. I had previously had trouble extracting the .dtx and .ins type files that are distributed with. The problem it seems was that my latex distribution is in "c:\program files" and the spaces cause problems.

I could imagine other people will have had this problem so in the more general case of updating a package manually under windows, try:

1) put your install file/files in a folder directly under c:\
2) run `latex <package>.idx` or latex `<package>.ins`
3) copy the generated .sty files out of the folder and either put them in the relevant folder in the latex installation. (which I gather is bad practice) or in: `C:\Documents and Settings\<user name>\Application Data\MiKTeX\<version>\<package name>\`

Though I haven't verified that the second choice will work.

I realise that I have actually answered a different question here, and it's slightly cack handed. It might be able to help some though and hopefully I can edit this answer if more experienced users are at odds with what I've said.

Answer (score 0):

no necessary to do above steps. Make it easy, uninstall it in pakage manager and re-install. that works well for me!

Comment: What do you mean with "above steps"? Please explain better, thanks and welcome to TeX.SE!